How to correctly download pdf and docx file in React JS?
I am trying to download docx or pdf file in React JS(depending on server response) when I get the response from the server. Backend is implemented in Python/Flask.
When I try to download the file, it downloads but damaged and corrupted.
React JS
const {
  isDownloadPdfDocumentSuccess, downloadPdfDocument,
  isDownloadDocDocumentSuccess,  downloadDocDocument,
} = useSelector(state => state.document)

useEffect(() => {
  if(isDownloadPdfDocumentSuccess || isDownloadDocDocumentSuccess) {
      downloadDocument(downloadPdfDocument || downloadDocDocument, 
      "application/pdf" || "application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
      officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
   }
}, [isDownloadPdfDocumentSuccess, isDownloadDocDocumentSuccess]);

function downloadDocument(downloadLink, downloadType) {
 const documentBlob = new Blob([downloadLink], { type: downloadType });
 const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(documentBlob);
 const anchor = document.createElement('a');
 anchor.href = url;
 anchor.download = document_title;
 document.body.appendChild(anchor);
 anchor.click();
 document.body.removeChild(anchor);
 window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url) ;
}

Backend Python/Flask
@app.route('/download_document_docx/<request_document_id>', methods=['GET'])
@token_required
def download_document_docx(current_user, request_document_id):
    '''
    Docx document preparation code
    '''
    return send_file(docx_file_path, as_attachment=True, mimetype="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")


It sounds like the main issue you're facing with file downloads is due to not handling the binary data properly in your React app. To solve this, you should adjust how you fetch and process the file from the server to ensure the data remains intact:
Use fetch to directly retrieve the file as a blob from the server. This ensures the data is handled correctly as binary data, not text, preventing corruption.
Here’s a shorter and modified version of your function:


function downloadDocument(downloadLink, documentTitle) {
    fetch(downloadLink)
    .then(response => response.blob())
    .then(blob => {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.href = url;
        anchor.download = documentTitle;
        document.body.appendChild(anchor);
        anchor.click();
        document.body.removeChild(anchor);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Download error:', error));
}



Ensure the file path is correct and the file isn't being altered or mishandled before sending.
Confirm that the MIME type in send_file matches the file type being sent.
This approach should help keep the file integrity intact during download, preventing the files from being corrupted. Make sure to test with different file types to ensure consistency.

It did not worked for me, it prints fetch errors, maybe because I am using redux and axios.
